# Repeat CSS transition/animation duration continuously on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I have a simple 2 sided "card" with a button on the front (labled "next") and another button on the back (labeled "back"). Each button triggers jquery to rotate the "card" vertically, using a transition-duration: 2s so it is visible that the card is being "flipped", instead of just an instant flip. My problem is that after I hit each button once, I can not get the "transition-duration / animation-duration" to trigger again. I can try to put it inside my Jquery function, but I do not understand why my CSS animation duration is not triggered on each button click (It only works for 1 click per button, the "card" flips accordingly to the back, and then to the front again once I press the buttons once). I have taken out most of the information from my form, so it is a little easier to tell what I am asking for. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='next']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("The NEXT Button Worked!");
    $(".form").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
  })
  $("input[name='back']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("The BACK Button Worked!");
    $(".formFlipAgain").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
  })
});

function showBack() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "block";
  }, 600);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "none";
  }, 600);
};

function showFront() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "block";
  }, 600);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "none";
  }, 600);
};
```

```css
.form {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
.formFlipAgain {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: space-between;
}
.formTitle {
  border-bottom: solid red;
}
.form-style-5 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 60%;
  max-height: 82vh;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
#form-style-5-Animation {
  animation: slide 3s 1;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 1000%, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);
  }
}
.form-style-5:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset {
  border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="location"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 select {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 textarea {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  height: 12%;
  /*Changing height for task textarea*/
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="location"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  height: 35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
  background: red;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="backButton"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:active,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:active {
  transform: translateY(3px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #b30000;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.next {
  -webkit-transition-duration: .01s;
  -moz-transition-duration: .01s;
  -o-transition-duration: .01s;
  transition-duration: .01s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
#backSide {
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
#backButton {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 15px;
  top: 3px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 27px;
  font-size: 105%;
  outline: 0;
}
#name,
#contact,
#location,
#misc,
#job {
  height: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="formFlipAgain">
  <div class="form" style="background-color:black">
    <div class="form-style-5" id="form-style-5-Animation">
      <div id="frontSide">
        <form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
          <input name="next" type="button" value="Next &#x21fe;" class="next" onClick="showBack();" />
      </div>
      <div id="backSide" style="display: none;">
        <input name="back" class="Button" type="button" onClick="showFront();" value="&#x21fd; &nbsp; back" id="backButton" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so...am i misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: @Carr No you perfectly solved my problem, THANKS A LOT! Simple solution, but it was a major blocker for me. Have a great day:)

Comment: It's my great pleasure ~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the result you want to achieve , you don't need 
extra class '.formFlipAgain' .You rotate the div with class '.form'  180 deg , and it remains in that situation and this causes the instant flip,
you just need to rotate it back .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='next']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("The NEXT Button Worked!");
    $(".form").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
  })
  $("input[name='back']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("The BACK Button Worked!");
    $(".form").css("transform", "rotateY(0deg)");
  })
});

function showBack() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "block";
  }, 600);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "none";
  }, 600);
};

function showFront() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("frontSide").style.display = "block";
  }, 600);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("backSide").style.display = "none";
  }, 600);
};
```

```css
.form {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
.formFlipAgain {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: space-between;
}
.formTitle {
  border-bottom: solid red;
}
.form-style-5 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 60%;
  max-height: 82vh;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
#form-style-5-Animation {
  animation: slide 3s 1;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 1000%, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);
  }
}
.form-style-5:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset {
  border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="location"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 select {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 textarea {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  height: 12%;
  /*Changing height for task textarea*/
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="location"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  height: 35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
  background: red;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="backButton"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:active,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:active {
  transform: translateY(3px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #b30000;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.next {
  -webkit-transition-duration: .01s;
  -moz-transition-duration: .01s;
  -o-transition-duration: .01s;
  transition-duration: .01s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
#backSide {
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
#backButton {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 15px;
  top: 3px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 27px;
  font-size: 105%;
  outline: 0;
}
#name,
#contact,
#location,
#misc,
#job {
  height: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="formFlipAgain">
  <div class="form" style="background-color:black">
    <div class="form-style-5" id="form-style-5-Animation">
      <div id="frontSide">
        <form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
          <input name="next" type="button" value="Next &#x21fe;" class="next" onClick="showBack();" />
      </div>
      <div id="backSide" style="display: none;">
        <input name="back" class="Button" type="button" onClick="showFront();" value="&#x21fd; &nbsp; back" id="backButton" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```